# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to convert my project to Swift 3, but I am getting an error message that the expression is too complex to be solved in reasonable time. I am not sure why this is, since this expression was working fine in Swift 2.2, but now all of a sudden it is taking so long?

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Here is the expression. It is basically a dictionary that will be used later with `SecItemCopyMatching` to extract an item from the keychain that was saved with a key tag. It performs a `touchID` to do this, since it was saved with that locking parameter:

```
let query : [String: AnyObject] = [String(kSecClass) : kSecClassGenericPassword,
     String(kSecAttrService) : keyTag as AnyObject,
     String(kSecAttrAccount) : keyTag,
     String(kSecReturnData) : kCFBooleanTrue,
     String(kSecMatchLimit) : kSecMatchLimitOne,
     String(kSecUseOperationPrompt) : message]
```

Comment: Have you looked through [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+too+complex+to+be+solved+in+reasonable+time) on the error message? You might find something useful.

Comment: The error "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time" is highly context-dependent. Sometimes exactly the same expression causes the error in a context, and does not in another context. You may need to show more context of your code, at least show how `keyTag` and `message` are declared.

Comment: `keyTag` and `message` are just strings.

Comment: "just strings" is not enough, `String`, `NSString` or `CFString`? All such things make difference.

Comment: `String`. However, the accepted answer solution fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to have to define your query as `var` and assign the values separately. It seems that Swift 3.0 cannot handle expressions this long.

Your code will look like this:

```
var query = [String: AnyObject]()
query[String(kSecClass)] = kSecClassGenericPassword
query[String(kSecAttrService)] =  keyTag as AnyObject
query[String(kSecAttrAccount)] = keyTag
query[String(kSecReturnData)] = kCFBooleanTrue
query[String(kSecMatchLimit)] = kSecMatchLimitOne
query[String(kSecUseOperationPrompt)] = message
```

Comment: Your compile time will be shorter this way, too. Hope the Swift team improve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting all dictionary values to `AnyObject`.  Unless they are already objects derived from `NSObject` (such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary)`, you need to cast them to `AnyObject`.  Swift 3 has removed the automatic bridging to Foundation types.

```
let query: [String: AnyObject] = [String(kSecClass) : kSecClassGenericPassword as AnyObject,
                                   String(kSecAttrService) : keyTag as AnyObject,
                                   String(kSecAttrAccount) : keyTag as AnyObject,
                                   String(kSecReturnData) : kCFBooleanTrue as AnyObject,
                                   String(kSecMatchLimit) : kSecMatchLimitOne as AnyObject,
                                   String(kSecUseOperationPrompt) : message as AnyObject]
```

Comment: This also seems to work. Haven't tested yet, but it gets rid of the error. Thanks